# Where to find books or course materials to help prepare for Esri Technical Certification in ArcGIS Desktop and Developer?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vba, certification

Where I can find books or course materials to help prepare for Esri Technical Certification in ArcGIS Desktop and Developer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check the [ESRI Technical Certification website](http://training.esri.com/certification/), under each level (e.g. Desktop 10.1) they provide a [PDF with a thorough list of resources](http://downloads2.esri.com/campus/downloads/certification/TrainingResources/TrainingResourcesEADA101.pdf) including training courses, web lessons and books from ESRI Press.

Comment: Thank you, But I am looking for a full online course that covers all fields of Esri Tecnical Certification in Arc Gis Desktop or  developer.

Comment: I think the idea of the certification is to gain the knowledge from many sources and demonstrate the knowledge in a test format - it's not designed to be a course that you "pass". Therefore, ESRI doesn't offer a one-stop-shop for the materials.

Comment: esri offers 2 instructor-led courses (not online courses) that cover all fields of ArcGIS Desktop certification exams: [Skills Review for ArcGIS Desktop Associate](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.courseDetail&CourseID=50124485_10.x) and  [Skills Review for ArcGIS Desktop Professional](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.courseDetail&CourseID=50124489_10.x)

Comment: Just as a complement for what @Radar has already mentioned,  visit the Esri Training web site where you can find lots of free web courses, recorded web seminars, and other materials. http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=search.results&cannedsearch=2 - here are the free ones.

Comment: The first link now redirects to https://www.esri.com/training/ and the second is broken

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://ESRICertification.com.  There's a bunch of ArcGISP Desktop, Developer, and ArcSDE questions on there to quiz yourself.

Comment: This link goes to a place that offers to sell you that domain name.

Answer (score -2):

I've just ordered and received this book "Python Scripting for ArcGIS":

http://www.amazon.ca/Python-Scripting-ArcGIS-Paul-Zandbergen/dp/1589482824

It covers up to 10.1 and so far I find it quite useful.

Comment: I agree, good book, however, it doesn't really have anything to do with the question and getting the certifications the OP asked about.

Comment: Yes it does. He said "Where can I find books or course material for esri arcgis desktop" That books is for ArcGIS desktop. Also, in addition to that, he also wanted to know about developer certification.